# Disappearing EMAs over OBV on timeframe change

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to overlay two EMAs over the OBV indicator, but when I switch timeframes both EMAs and the OBV seem to disappear, but are just out of view. How do I make the indicators rest to centre of view across all timeframes?

```
            //@version=4
            study(title="OBV+EMA", shorttitle="OBV+EMA", precision=0, format=format.volume)

            src = close
            len20 = input(20, minval=1, title="Length")
            len200 = input(200, minval=1, title="Length")


            changesrc = change(src)
            obv = cum(changesrc > 0 ? volume : changesrc < 0 ? -volume : 0*volume)

            ema20 = ema(obv, len20)
            ema200 = ema(obv, len200)

            plot(obv, title="OBV", color=#03adfc, linewidth=1)
            plot(ema20, title="EMA 20", color=#fcd703, linewidth=1)
            plot(ema200, title="EMA 200", color=#ffffff, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

On balance volume has a built-in `ta.obv` (Pine v5).
I rewrote your script to v5, and this works fine on all timeframes.
If you should have an example of where it goes wrong, please post a ticker and timeframes and a screenshot if possible.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="OBV+EMA", shorttitle="OBV+EMA", precision=0, format=format.volume)

var float   src         = input.source(close, 'Source')
var int     lenShort    = input.int(20,  "Length (short)", 1)
var int     lenLong     = input.int(200, "Length (long)",  1)

emaShort = ta.ema(ta.obv, lenShort)
emaLong  = ta.ema(ta.obv, lenLong)

plot(ta.obv,   "OBV",       color.blue)
plot(emaShort, "EMA Short", color.yellow)
plot(emaLong,  "EMA Long",  color.white)
```

Comment: Thanks man. I just pasted the code in and but the issue still stand. When I reset the pane the indicator shows, even when i change timeframe, but its when i adjust the scale up or down then change timeframe does the indicator disappear out of view.

Comment: Ah, I see. Just right-click the scale of the indicator pane and select "reset price scale".